# How can I get result ofr Dataframe in terms of another array items by using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a problem about how to get selecting country result in terms of array items.

I can list some countries defined in dataframe

```
for i in range(df_countries.shape[0]):
    print(str(df_countries['Country_Region'][i]))
```

I want to get results in terms of above result but I don't know how to do that.

I can write this code but it doesn't work.

```
df.loc[df["Country"].apply(lambda x: x== [(df_countries['Country_Region'][i]) for i in range(df_countries.shape[0]) ])]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve it out with the help of this code

```
corona_confirmed_df = corona_df[corona_df['Country'].isin([ str(df_confirmed['Country_Region'][i]) for i in range(df_confirmed.shape[0]) ])]
```

Comment: The best solution here would be with loc. Doing this:

- Will check if your country is in a list with duplicates 
- is much more complex to read then the .loc solution
- Is likely to be much slower than the .loc solution

Small tip: if you're trying to do .isin, it can be a good idea to convert your list to a unique list of values, or to a set (set(my_list))

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be,

```
df.loc[df.Country == df.Country_Region]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

You can do something like this:

```
df_countries.apply(lambda row: row["Country"] == row["Country_Region"], axis=1)
```

You can then use .loc to select the rows that match this condition.

I admit I'm not sure I understood your question, so I hope this helps.

Also, you can use [pandas.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through the rows of a DataFrame (this doesn't answer your question but it seems you were doing this in the beginning of your post :) )

---

Edit:
The answer below by Vishnudev is actually a better answer in this case:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Country'] == df.loc[:, 'Country_Region'], :]
```